# How to convert a multiline if statement to a single line if statement using unix script?

Tags: bash, scripting

In a file I have multiple if conditions like below:

```
if ( a==b ||
c!=d &&
(e>f))
{
do something
}
```

I have to convert each multiline if statement to single line if statement i.e

```
if ( a==b || c!=d && (e>f))
{
do something
}
```

How can I do this conversion using Unix scripting?

Comment: "{ do something }"  part can remain as it is without any changes

Comment: i just want " if (.....) in a single line

Comment: Crossposting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45779509/3776858

Comment: Crossposting: https://askubuntu.com/q/947997/336375

Answer (score 4):

Run it through an indentation tool such as `indent` or `clang-format`. These know the C and C++ grammar rules and will reformat your code according to how you configure them. `clang-format` is even using the same language parser as the `clang` compiler.

For example:

```
$ cat test.c
if ( a==b ||
c!=d &&
(e>f))
{
/* do something */
}

$ clang-format test.c
if (a == b || c != d && (e > f)) {
  /* do something */
}

$ clang-format --style="{BreakBeforeBraces: Allman}" test.c
if (a == b || c != d && (e > f))
{
  /* do something */
}

$ indent -kr -st <test.c
if (a == b || c != d && (e > f)) {
/* do something */
}

$ indent -kr -bl -st < test.c
if (a == b || c != d && (e > f))
{
/* do something */
}
```

The `indent` used in the example above is GNU `indent`, not the default `indent` found on BSD systems.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any logic for this or any other solution apart from using predefined tools?

Comment: The logic is that it's difficult to write a shell script that flawlessly parses C or C++ syntax, and since there already are well tested tools that does exactly what you want to do, you ought to use these instead of trying to write a C language parser yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with `awk`:

```
awk '(/^\{/ || flag)&&/^[^}]/{printf "\n%s",$0;flag=1} 
      /^\}/{flag=0; printf "\n}\n" ;next} 
     (!flag){printf "%s ",$0}' infile.txt
```